# Attempting to remove string between two strings, whilst omitting the string if - sed

Tags: sed

I'm having some trouble when attempting to remove a string between the string end and the character ;.
At the moment it looks like I'm also picking up the string if on other lines as that string is also between end and ;. I've been attempting to omit the if string from the command but I don't seem to be having much look using the below sed command as I receive a error. The string triggername is what needs to be removed, but it's not consistently named that.

Example File Before:

```
end if;
    end triggername ;
```

Example File Expected:

```
end if;
    end;
```

The command I've been attempting to use is:

```
sed -i -e '/if/! s/\(end.*)\;/g' test
```

I was hoping the /if/! would omit all literal if strings from the next command but when I attempt to run it I receive the following error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 20: unterminated `s' command
```

Can anyone help me understand why I'm getting that error please? And if the sed command is mainly correct, if not what would you recommend to improve it.

Update1:

Thank you! As suggested I've tried adding in an extra / at the end as I just require it removing not replaced. But now I have this error: `sed -i -e '/if/! s/\(end.*)\;//' test
sed: -e expression #1, char 20: Unmatched ( or \(`

To me it looks like I have a closing bracket not too sure about the '\' . I have only done this a once before, so quite new.

Comment: The correct syntax is: `s/pattern/replacement/modifiers`, but you have `s/pattern/modifiers` (missing replacement).

Comment: Thank you, I have updated my post as I'm still quite confused

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Your first attempt misses the `replacement` part from `s/pattern/replacement/modifiers` syntax.
2. You forgot to escape the closing bracket: Use `\)`.
3. No need to escape the semicolon though.
4. Your pattern includes all of `end.*;`. So all this will get removed. Use `\1;` as replacement.

In total:

```
sed -i -e '/if/!s/\(end\).*;/\1;/' file
```

Or as `end` is a static word and .* includes the `;` you can simplify it:

```
sed -i -e '/if/!s/end.*/end;/' file
```

Comment: Thank you, that was a good explanation makes a lot of sense. If I also needed to omit another word from the removal, would it be a case of adding another /<word>/! either before or straight after the if one, or is it more complex than that?